# Solving two coupled second order boundary value problems

Tags: python, numpy, ode, differential-equations

I have solved a single second order differential equation with two boundary conditions using the module `solve_bvp`. However, now I am trying to solve the system of two second order differential equations;

> U'' + a*B' = 0
>
> B'' + b*U' = 0

with the boundary conditions U(+/-0.5) = +/-0.01 and B(+/-0.5) = 0. I have split this into a system of first ordinary differential equations and I am trying to use `solve_bvp` to solve them numerically. However, I am just getting arrays full of zeros for my solution. I believe I am implementing the boundary conditions wrong. It is not clear to me how to handle more than two equations from the documentation. My attempt is below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
alpha = 1E-8
zeta = 8E-3
C_k = 0.05
sigma = 0.01
def fun(x, y):

    return np.vstack((y[1],-((alpha)/(C_k*sigma))*y[2],y[2], -(1/(C_k*zeta))*y[1]))

def bc(ya, yb):

    return np.array([ya[0]+0.001, yb[0]-0.001,ya[0]-0, yb[0]-0])

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 5000)
y = np.zeros((4, x.size))
print(y)


sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)
print(sol)
```

In my question I have just relabeled a and b, but they're just parameters that I input. I have the analytic solution for this set of equations so I know one exists that is non-trivial. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most times really helpful if you state at least once in a comment or by assignment to specifically named variables *how you want to compose the state vector.*

By the form of the derivative return vector, I would think you intend

```
U, U',  B, B'
```

which means that `U=y[0], U'=y[1]` and `B=y[2],B'=y[3]`, so that your derivatives vector should correctly be

```
return y[1], -((alpha)/(C_k*sigma))*y[3],  y[3], -(1/(C_k*zeta))*y[1]
```

and the boundary conditions

```
return ya[0]+0.001, yb[0]-0.001, ya[2]-0, yb[2]-0
```

Especially your boundary condition should throw the algorithm in the first step because of a singular Jacobian, always check the `.success` field and the `.message` field of the solution structure.

---

Note that by default the absolute and relative tolerance of the experimental `solve_bvp` is `1e-3`, and the number of nodes is limited to `500`.

Setting the initial node number to 50 (5000 is much too much, the solver refines where necessary), and the tolerance to `1-6`, I get the following solution plots that visibly satisfy the boundary conditions.

[image]

Comment: So I've written the equations as the four odes such that U' = V, V' = -((alpha/(C_k*sigma))*H, B' = H, H' = -(1/(C_k*zeta))*V - I hope this is clear. I just tried the code you gave, and the boundary conditions are not being satisfied by the solution for B, i.e 0 at the boundaries. I am a little confused on how you've written the return vector for the derivatives. If you could explain further I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Ok, so I may have fixed it and noticed it agrees with the edit you have put on your comment. However, the solution for B still does not satisfy the zero boundary condition. Is there something you notice in the code? It looks like the true solution, but upside down and the boundaries aren't satisfied. Maybe I have missed a negative on my equations.

Comment: As far as I can see, my return vector is compatible with your comments. The scipy solvers automatically convert the returned list into an appropriate numpy structure, so you do not need to do this manually.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, this has been really helpful. How do you set the tolerance in the bvp function?

Comment: With the option `tol=1e-7`. You can increase the number of nodes with `max_nodes=1500` or higher as necessary, but that is not needed here, unless you use `tol=1e-12` or lower. If you can, rescale the problem so that the typical scale of all solution components is around `1`, I think the heuristics in the solver are built around that assumption.

Comment: Hi @Lutz your previous answer was very useful. I have posted another question regarding a very similar issue. I have added an extra equation which is independent of the first two coupled equations, but depends on their solutions. However, I am getting the same error that my jacobian is singular. I have followed what you have done, but it does not seem to fix it. Any help would be appreicated greatly.